# "404 Not Found" when updating the package list using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Trying to update my Apt-based Sytems (Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy)), I am getting this error

any recommendations?

```
# apt-get update
Err http://packages.cloudkick.com intrepid Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'packages.cloudkick.com'
Hit http://agentrepo.drivesrvr.com serveragent Release.gpg                                                                                                              
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release.gpg
```

and

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy Release    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

and more

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardy and anything prior 12.04 is unsupported and has their repositories moved to `http://old-archive.ubuntu.com`. These doesn't get upgraded packages and could be a security risk of using. I would recommend you upgrading as soon as possible.

`http://packages.cloudkick.com` is dead.

Comment: exactly the problem, I am on a Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy) instance. thx

Comment: @joelmaranhao if it helped you, please accept the answer. Also, please, I ask you this as internet denizen UPGRADE UBUNTU!